# Two-way linked cells after filtering operation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

EDIT: someone rightfully pointed out my question was too specific and ill posed, I apologise for that and trying to fix this by changing my wording and referring to the generic case!

Hi everyone!

I have a problem that can be summarised into two main questions and will essentially produce a dynamical spreadsheet.

I have done some tries using VBA macros in Excel, but then I realised these won't be available in SharePoint anyway, so I am exploring Google Sheets as a possible alternative.

---

Now, to the problem: let's say we have a starting workbook named "THING", in which we have a *sheet* "PEOPLE" that is shaped like this:

```
NAME | VALUE | EVENT 1 | EVENT 2 | ...
 x   |   x   |   yes   |   no    | ...
.
.
```

**FIRST QUESTION**

How do you split this first spreadsheet using a criteria (eg. "VALUE") into multiple *sheets* in the workbook, so that we have *sheet* "VALUE x", "VALUE y" etc.?

**SECOND QUESTION**

How do you achieve two-way linked cells after a filtering operation (ie. dinamically)? Basically, how can I edit an EVENT cell in *sheet* "GROUP x" and make it so that the original "PEOPLE" tab gets edited too?

---

If anyone can help would be much appreciated, even by just pointing out resources or any other previous similar question that I missed in my research (in that case sorry about double posting!).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Comment: why not making the PEOPLE sheet the reunion of all the per group sheets ? So adding people, editing people would be done in per group sheet and the PEOPLE one would automatically get all the info, but would not allow editing

Comment: what you are looking for is Database Software

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can simply use `onEdit()` simple trigger, and add any functionality to it. In your case you set edited value in another sheet.
More on that in [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

P.S. some time ago I made an example for someone here, you can look it up. It's [two-way spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDlBaWtC7Mwh-FEhiZM6Co0OTj3aH-62ACbyAXlTtnA/edit#gid=45422222) and works with any input, dropdown and checkboxes also!